# PnP PowerShell script to set folder permissions within a document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get all folders and subfolders within a doucument library in SharePoint online. I am want to check whether they have subfoldes or not. If they do, I wan't to change the permissions for Members and Visitors to "Read".

I am new to PnP and tried this script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite -UseWebLogin

$folders = Get-PnPFolder -Includes ListItemAllFields -Url "/sites/mysite/my document library" | Where-Object { $_.ListItemAllFields.FSObjType -eq 0 }

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Get-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id

    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id -User "Members" -AddRole "Read"

    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id -User "Visitors" -AddRole "Read"
}

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Unfortunately the $folders variable is empty, even though it should not be. Therefore, the permissions are not changed for my folders. I also do not know if the script is only working for the folders in "/sites/mysite/my document library" and ignores the subfolders and their subfolders.

I appreciate any help or sources on how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: in order to get sub folders you should try Get-PnPFolderInFolder command

Answer (score 0):

You can check the folder or subfolder using the ListItemAllFields.FSObjType eq 1  condition.

Here is a modified script as per your requirement.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite -UseWebLogin

function Set-FolderPermissions($folder) {
    Get-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id

    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id -User "Members" -AddRole "Read"

    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "my document library" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id -User "Visitors" -AddRole "Read"

    $subfolders = Get-PnPFolder -Includes ListItemAllFields -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folder.ServerRelativeUrl | Where-Object { $_.ListItemAllFields.FSObjType -eq 1 }
    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
        Set-FolderPermissions $subfolder
    }
}

$rootFolders = Get-PnPFolder -Includes ListItemAllFields -Url "/sites/mysite/my document library" | Where-Object { $_.ListItemAllFields.FSObjType -eq 0 }

foreach ($rootFolder in $rootFolders) {
    Set-FolderPermissions $rootFolder
}

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```